# Deploy UWP on release: error 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found

Tags: mobile, deployment, uwp, release

When I want to deploy my Project onto my Windows Lumia 640, in debug mode everything is OK, but on release the app fails immediately. 
Details of the exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x77269C83 (ntdll.dll) in Program.exe: 0xC0000139:
>   Entry Point Not Found. The thread 0x994 has exited with code
>   -1073741511 (0xc0000139). The program '[2296] Program.exe' has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139) 'Entry Point Not Found'.

I have really no idea what to do since my NuGet packages are updated. Sadly this exception won't localize the location of the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a know issues that you should close `Complie with .net native tool chain`

In your project property that you can see the Build tab.

Close the Complie with .net native tool chain

Then you should rebuild the project and it can run.

See [UWP app fails to start because of 'Entry Point Not Found' exception · Issue #267 · xamarin/Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/267)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an ancient question, but I still get this problem every other build and deselecting the "Compile with .net native toolchain" is not an option if you want to deploy to Windows Store.

Solve this by updating the Target version under the "Project Settings > Application" to the latest possible:
[image]

Comment: I'm still on VS2017. I was just using the options available to me. It didn't hit me to try and update the Universal SDK on my machine until I saw your screen shot there and how far behind mine were. Hope this fixes things because my first UWP deploy only ran on 4 out of 6 machines I tried it on. "Runs on any Windows 10 system". Yeah, about that... LOL. Thanks.